# Where to place methods that consume multiple object collections

Tags: object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design, methods

We've been battling over where certain methods should live within our domain model, so looking for some adice and reasoning as to where they should go.

Say we have a `Project` object now that `Project` can have a `Budget` (which is essentially made up of a number of hours against certain job roles and these have a cost to them), `Timesheets`, `Invoices`, `External Costs`.
We have a number of calculations throughout are system to work out what the total budget of the project is, what the total cost of our project is and then comparing the 2.

The question is where do these calculations live: Do they live on the `Project` and simply act against the `Timesheet,Invoice,Externals` collections on there to get the correct number. If so then we need to make sure these collections are correctly populated before performing the calculation (lots of null checking etc).

Or they could live in a separate class where the `Timesheet,Invoice,Externals` are passed in and the result passed back. This way we know that we'd have to have retrieved the correct data in order to perform the calculation.

Comment: I think you want to start with a different question.  The question should be how does the consuming client get their work done: what is the usage model for these object(s).  You're looking into implementation details before looking at consuming client usage.  We want the client to be simple and the usage model foolproof so they fall into the pit of success.

Comment: Since nulls are a problem in one case and not in the other, I assume you have some kind of lazy loading going on? Also, these calculations seem to be relevant business-related concepts (that have some business logic associated with them), so one thing to seriously consider is creating objects to explicitly represent either the use cases involving these computations, or the computations themselves, and then you can place your methods in there (as well as any computation-specific state).

Answer (score 1):

In Domain Driven Design, the concept of an Aggregate Root exists.

An Aggregate should always be in a valid state, meaning that all children (entities, value objects) should be loaded into the Aggregate, so that it can perform the operations without having to worry about whether the children are available.

Whether it's a good idea to add the collections depends on if you actually have behavior in the Project aggregate that requires access to the collections. It might be enough for the Project aggregate to have a `TotalExternalCost` property for example.

Answer (score 0):

OOD and DDD differ on this significantly.

**Object-orientation** says that there is no reason to have any objects unless they have some useful (i.e. business-related instead of technical) *behavior*. So unless you can assign useful behavior to `Timesheet`, `Invoice`, etc., they should not exist. That leaves us with `Project.calculateCost()` or something similar. It doesn't matter how or on what data this is done, or where that data comes from. Again, if you do have some useful behavior in other things, you can use those in `Project`.

If you have to have null-checks you're doing it wrong. It either means that you use objects as essentially free-for-all data-structures, or use lots of implicitly assigned semantics. Or both. Neither is good.

Mainstream **DDD** is completely different from what I described above. That would say that data-structures are fine, and you should build a replica of all data in-memory, perform some procedure on them, and then push data back wherever they came from. Logic only lives in the "model" if it can be done completely "purely". Logic that needs multiple things usually then resides in *Services* that act on the "model" completely from the outside.

You have to decide for one, they are not compatible.

Comment: Downvote means my answer is working :)

Comment: Didn’t downvote but I am curious. DTOs didn’t seem like anything but a necessary evil due to leaving code under my control in either OO or DDD. I thought DDD was about building a ubiquitous language from a bounded context. Can you cite what Eric Evans teaches about naked data?

Comment: @candied_orange You have a point. Eric Evans in my reading of the book was not strongly for or against anemic designs. He does hint at it, with layered architecture, talking dismissively about oo. But you're right, the value, for me at least was elsewhere. However, I was careful to say "mainstream DDD". When somebody says DDD, they *usually* mean the Vaughn Vernon type DDD, which is the strict "entity/value object/services/repositories/aggregates" and all that technical stuff. Where entities have to be "pure", i.e. they can't use technology, i.e. they stay mostly data.

Comment: pure means no behavior huh? Can you cite that from Vaughn Vernon?

Comment: "the domain model should be free of technology." Page 46 of DDD Distilled. I can do one better though, here is his repo: https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples. Take a look at some classes like `Post`, `Forum`, how much of the public methods is just dealing with it being a data structure and how much is actual behavior? Also, I didn't say no behavior at all. I said "pure" things like pure calculations, adding/removing from lists, things like that are apparently allowed. Those could be considered behavior in some circumstances I guess.

Comment: before you go thinking that idea is alien to OO please look up POJOs.

Comment: “*free of technology*” means no database access code, no frameworks, stuff like that, it does **not** mean *no behavior*. And about Vernon’s repo, here’s the Forum class and I would not call it anemic https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_collaboration/src/main/java/com/saasovation/collaboration/domain/model/forum/Forum.java

Comment: @RikD Re: `Forum`. There are 21 public methods. 8 of them are straight getters for *all* the internal fields. So right off the bat, there is no hidden state. Really bad start for an object. Additional 2 are variations on these. Then there are method like `changeDescription()` which sets the description, so let's just call that a setter. There are 5 of these. Then there is `moderatePost` which just alters the `Post` structure, and `startDiscussion(For)`. Let's be nice and call those 2 behavior. The 3 remaining is equals()/hashCode()/toString(). Overall a poor excuse for an object.

Comment: The object might not contain much complex business logic, but that doesn’t make it anemic. The bit of logic it does perform is nicely encapsulated within the class. A nice starting point for new requirements with more complex logic.

Comment: @RikD Technically you're right, it's not 100% anemic. But, based on the count above it's 90% anemic, which is still pretty bad, considering you should approach 0%. However I can't accept the argument that anything is "encapsulated". Its state is completely public, therefore no encapsulation is possible. Let's put it this way: If I were to move the `moderatePost` method out of `Forum`, would it still work? The answer is yes. That's not encapsulated logic, that is just a convenience method that I could just as easily ignore and could still do anything I wish from the outside.

Comment: Why is it 90% anemic? Go read Fowler’s article again, it would *become* anemic if you move methods out of the class to external services, but since that not the case, isn’t it 0% anemic? And I used encapsulation in the sense that the class bundles data and behavior; I realize that in some definitions *data hiding* is also part of encapsulation and that I agree is lacking in this example.

Comment: @RikD It is 90% anemic because only 2 out of 21 public methods could be argued to be behavior. Here is a quote from Fowler's article: "and you realize that there is hardly any behavior on these objects, making them little more than bags of getters and setters". That exactly describes the `Forum` class, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: No, because you left out this part: “*Instead there are a set of service objects which capture all the domain logic, carrying out all the computation and updating the model objects with the results*”. If there’s no separation between the model and the service classes, it can’t be called an anemic model.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam It's not clear what alternate design you'd propose for the `Forum` example that in your eyes wouldn't be anemic? How would you fulfill the same command use cases differently? `assignModerator`, `changeDescription`, `changeSubject`, `close`, `moderatePost`, `reopen`, etc. These are all behaviors to fufill business use cases. You may argue that `changeDescription` is the same as `setDescription`, but if that's the use case then that's the needed behavior. What would be anemic in my eyes is if `Forum` would only define DUMB getters/setters and all logic would be in services.

Comment: @plalx `Forum.assignModerator` is *not* the business use-case, `ForumApplicationService.assignModeratorToForum` is. Or I think that it supposed to be, it is hard to tell, because it is not used anywhere. So the logic that I actually would want *is* in a service, and `Forum` defines only dumb setter/getters, that's exactly your last sentence.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam Dumb setters are direct assignments without any conditionals. `Forum` does encapsulate the "business" logic where the application's service encapsulates the "orchestration" or "glue" logic. I mean, you could put everything in the model à la Active Record, but that's a different business logic pattern that has much less seperation of concerns.